# is CAVLC decoder enough for entropy part

Tags: h.264, entropy

Is CAVLC decoder enough to decode an encoded bitstream in H.264 ? or Exp_Golomb decoder must be implemented also? (for baseline profile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question stipulates baseline profile. It's true that baseline is restricted to using CAVLC, so a baseline-only decoder will not need to implement CABAC. However, there are various pieces of even a baseline stream which require exponential-Golomb coding.

So, yes: CAVLC and exponential-Golomb decoding (as well as inverse transforms, prediction, motion compensation, and other features) are necessary to decode a baseline H.264 stream.